# Eclipse won't open after new java update

Tags: java, eclipse

I have recently updated my JDK, Eclipse subsequently would not open, thus in side of the Eclipse.ini file I changed the path to the new version of Java.  Even after doing such, Java still came up with an error saying to check the medadata in my workplace.  I then attempted to enter the -clean command inside of the Eclipse.ini and it still would not open.  Do you have any idea of what I can do to fix my Eclipse work environment?

In the log the most recent addition is:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-03-10 15:40:17.497
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
...

Eclipse is Neon 3
Java is 11.0.2

Comment: can you post the app logs of eclipse ?

Comment: What version of Eclipse? What version of Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse Neon support only JDK 8.
But you can force it with some plugin.
https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/9nsknz/eclipse_support_for_java_11/

Comment: That's not true. Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10) has built-in Java 11 support. Please correct your answer: Eclipse Neon is pretty old and have to be upgraded to 2018-12 (4.10) to be able to write Java 11 code.

Comment: My bad, Eclipse Neon not Eclipse IDE 2018‑12.

Comment: Eclipse Neon has been released 2016, more than two years before Java 11. The mentioned plugin will not work in Neon. It is recommended to upgrade to 2018-12.